# questions about facebook oauth migration

Tags: facebook, oauth

When Oct 1 rolls around, I want to make sure my games are covered. So in that light, I have a couple of questions.

I understand I need to offer SSL version, which is done, but does that mean that the http version is going away? or will it just mean that all apps will require both versions, rather than being able to leave one blank?

With the dashboard increment calls going away, what prompts the system  to add a [1] next to the app in the sidebar when the player has something they need to do? unless the app has some way of telling the facebook server that a user has some task they need to perform, how is that going to increment?

with the new "manage_notifications" permission, does this imply that after a long haitus, apps will once again be able to post messages to a users notification drop down? which would be great and would make the previous dashboard question void.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL version is required for your users who have secure browsing enabled in their security settings. Without an https version your app is not accessible to users who opt for secure browsing.

The [1] that you see next to the apps is the number of pending requests sent using the request Dialog.
For more details...https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/